# Extract Erlang tuples in list

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I got the tuples in the list:

```erlang
Contents = [{john, [jill,joe,bob]},
            {jill, [bob,joe,bob]},
            {sue, [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]},
            {bob, [john]},
            {joe, [sue]}],
```

The print I want to get is:

```
john: [jill,joe,bob]
jill: [bob,joe,bob]
sue: [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]
bob: [john]
joe: [sue]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use `lists:foreach/2` or can try implement your own function for iteration and print out lists items:

```erlang
1> Contents = [{john, [jill,joe,bob]},
{jill, [bob,joe,bob]},
{sue, [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]},
{bob, [john]},
{joe, [sue]}].
2> lists:foreach(fun({K, V}) -> 
  io:format("~p : ~p~n", [K, V]) 
end, Contents).
```

Custom function:

```erlang
% call: print_content(Contents).
print_content([]) ->
  ok;
print_content([{K, V}|T]) ->
  io:format("~p : ~p~n", [K, V]),
  print_content(T).
```

Lists generators:

```erlang
1> [io:format("~p : ~p~n", [K, V]) ||  {K, V} <- Contents].
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over the list in whatever way you like, and extract the tuples with pattern matching:

```
{ Name, ListOfNames } = X
```

where `X` is the current item from your list. Then you can print them as desired.